# How to place images at an exact position

Tags: spacing, floats, wrapfigure

```
    \begin{figure}[t]\vspace{-1cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{squarew1}
\caption{Simulation for $T_1$}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{squarew2}
\caption{Simulation for $T_2$}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{squarew3}
\caption{Simulation for $T_3$}
\end{figure}

\section*{Citation}
\begin{itemize}
\item Decade (log scale). (2021, March 02). Retrieved from \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decade_(log_scale)}{the link}
\item Zhang, Q. (2013). Frequency Response of ideal low pass filter. Researchgate.Net. \href{https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Frequency-Response-of-ideal-low-pass-filter_fig5_259436922}{the link}
\item Alonso, G. (2020). LTspice: Generating Triangular \& Sawtooth Waveforms. Https://Www.Analog.Com/. \href{https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-generating-triangular-sawtooth-waveforms.html}{the link}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

In the pdf figures appear after citation which I cannot fix.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6LjNDMW

Comment: For future reference: You can both edit your question and add pictures to it directly. There is no need for an external link.